# How to install gnome-schedule on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: gnome, cron, schedule

Finally upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04 and my favorite application gnome-schedule (I somehow managed to install it for 20.04) is not working.

I tried to follow install instructions here https://gitlab.gnome.org/World/gnome-schedule

But it does not work. PyGtk for python2 (which is installed and works) are the problem (can not install)...

Can you please advise on how to make this work? Thanks.

Comment: There is a python3 fork https://github.com/rizalmart/gtock. However, the installation would involve manually copying the directories to their proper locations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fork of GNOME Schedule (ported to GTK3) is available at https://github.com/rizalmart/gtock.

---

**Warning**: The developer is working on implementing meson build system. Right now, the [recommended method](https://github.com/rizalmart/gtock/issues/2#issuecomment-1483952430) of installation is to copy the source packages to your `/usr` folder, which is dangerous if you type a wrong command. I have verified that this method works, but **use this method at your own risk**.

---

First, install cron, which is a dependency.

```
sudo apt install cron
```

Then, clone the repository.

```
git clone https://github.com/rizalmart/gtock.git --depth=1
```

Copy the relevant folder to your `usr`.

```
sudo cp -r $HOME/gtock/gtock-src/usr/* /usr/
```

Mark the relevant binaries and the .desktop as executable.

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/gtock
sudo chmod +x /usr/share/applications/gtock.desktop
```

Finally, compile the glib-schemas.

```
sudo glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/
```

---

You can open it with the command `gtock`, or open `Scheduled Task` in the menu.

Comment: Thanks. This indeed makes gtock operational on Ubuntu 22.04. This command: `sudo cp -r $HOME/gtock/gtock-src/usr/ /usr/` creates a `/usr` subfolder in `/usr` so one has `/usr/usr/` ... I would suggest an edit.

Comment: @user947967 Done. Can you please check?